# Использование django и PostgreSQL

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql

У меня есть такая задача: должен быть сайт на django и бот для телеграм, они должны брать данные из одной БД (таблицы тоже общие). У бота должна быть возможность записать в БД что-нибудь, но я не хочу это делать напрямую, потому что django по-своему называет таблицы и поля в них + миграции и так далее, мне кажется это не самый лучший вариант и лучше записывать данные с помощью django crm.
Вопрос: Как можно вызвать функцию из views.py из бота, без http запроса, чтобы записать или достать что-то из БД. Возможно есть способы лучше, выполняющие мою задачу?

Comment: Можно из кода бота использовать Django ORM.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я не пробовал, но разве это будет работать? По-моему я не смогу просто взять и импортировать какую-нибудь модель из приложений django и мне вначале нужно импортировать что-то другое

Comment: Придётся выполнить [немножко подготовительных действий](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#initialization-process), но будет.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а можно, пожалуйста, больше информации про дополнительные действия?

Comment: По ссылке подробно описан процесс инициализации Django. ORM для работы нужен инициализированный реестр приложений и доступ к настройкам.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо, не увидел ссылку)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev всё понятно кроме одного: как указать какой именно проект импортировать? Т.е. допустим у меня есть папка с кучей проектов на django, как система должна понять откуда именно импортировать приложения?